# CoreML: Unable to perform matrix multiplication

Tags: coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to implement a matrix multiplication operation in my network using NetworkBuilder.
I wish to multiply two tensors of size (20x50) and (50x100) to get a tensor of size (20x100).

How can I do that? I've tried to use add_batched_mat_mul but I'm getting the below error on coremltools==3.0b3 and coremltools==3.0b4

How can I perform a matmul operation with the above mentioned tensor dimensions?

Error on coremltools==3.0b3

```
RuntimeWarning: You will not be able to run predict() on this Core ML model. Underlying exception message was: Error compiling model: "Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: Unsupported layer type (CoreML.Specification.NeuralNetworkLayer) for layer 'matmul'.".
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Error on coremltools==3.0b4

```
  File "test2.py", line 28, in <module>
    out = model.predict({"matrix_left": np.zeros((20, 50, 1))})
  File "python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py", line 345, in predict
    raise Exception('Unable to load CoreML.framework. Cannot make predictions.')
Exception: Unable to load CoreML.framework. Cannot make predictions.
exception loading model proxy: dlopen(python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/libcoremlpython.so, 2): Symbol not found: _objc_opt_class
  Referenced from: python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/libcoremlpython.so (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/libcoremlpython.so
```

Script used:

```
import coremltools.models.datatypes as datatypes
from coremltools.models.neural_network import NeuralNetworkBuilder
from coremltools.models import MLModel

import numpy as np

model_input_features = [
    ("matrix_left", datatypes.Array(20, 50, 1)),
]
model_output_features = [
    ("y", datatypes.Array(20, 100, 1)),
]

builder = NeuralNetworkBuilder(input_features=model_input_features, output_features=model_output_features)

np.random.seed(42)

matrix_right = np.random.rand(50, 100, 1)
builder.add_load_constant(name="matrix_right", output_name="y",
                          constant_value=matrix_right, shape=(50, 100, 1))


builder.add_batched_mat_mul(name="matmul", input_names=["matrix_left", "matrix_right"],
                            output_name="y")

model = MLModel(builder.spec)
out = model.predict({"matrix_left": np.zeros((20, 50, 1))})
y = out["y"]
print(y)
print(y.shape)
```

I've also tried using dot product using add_elementwise, but get the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: You will not be able to run predict() on this Core ML model. 
Underlying exception message was: Error compiling model: "compiler error:  Dot product layer: 'matmul': 
height dimension of the input blob must be 1.".
```

Script:

```
matrix_right = np.random.rand(50, 100, 1)
builder.add_load_constant(name="matrix_right", output_name="matrix_right", constant_value=matrix_right, shape=(50, 100, 1))
builder.add_elementwise("matmul", input_names=["matrix_left", "matrix_right"], output_name="y", mode="DOT")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
builder.add_load_constant(name="matrix_right", output_name="matrix_right",
                      constant_value=matrix_right, shape=(50, 100, 1))
```

Note that the output name is now `"matrix_right"` instead of `"y"`.

The model still doesn't work with 3.0b3 or 3.0b4 but at least it's a valid model now. :-)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the model, but is there no way I can perform a matmul operation in CoreML? Why is it proving to be so difficult?

Comment: I've tried using dot product using eadd_elementwise but it breaks as well.

Comment: It's being difficult because it's a beta version. Your best bet is to file a bug report with Apple, or wait until the next beta and hope it's fixed. Also, have you tried it in Xcode? The fact that it doesn't work from coremltools is usually because it's been linked against a different version than whatever your Xcode is providing, but running the model from within a macOS/iOS project shouldn't have that problem.